# Nav li redirects to another section in another page

Tags: html, href, navbar, scrollspy

I have two html pages in two different folders, they both have the same navbar, lets suppose they're named page1 and page2, i want the nav li's in page2 to redirect me to a specific section in page1, how can i do that?
i tried this but it didn't work:

```
<a href="../foldername/page1.html#sectionid"></a>
```

Comment: you can use https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h

Comment: what you posted above should already work. what's the problem?

Comment: @Avihaym answering questions about completely different subjects (like here) with "use bootstrap" really doesn't help anyone... (the question is about links - bootstrap has nothing to do with links)

Comment: @Johannes it's not working, im using scrollspy as well so i want it to go to the section in the other page then scroll down to the given section but its not going anywhere it stays where it is

Comment: ah, okay. Most likely scrollspy is preventing the default action of jumping to the anchor. Does it go to the top of the page or directly to the linked section (without scrolling)?

Comment: neither, it stays on the same page

Comment: @jissylarry I had a similar question once here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36137841/5641669 and got a useful answer. However, I didn't use scrollspy, but Scrollmagic. Maybe you can use that solution anyways...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an HTML element with `id="sectionid"` in the page 1 in order to the HTML bookmark to work.
For example:

```
<h2 id="sectionid">BOOKMARK</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Clients">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And then on the related articles for example:

```
    <div class="article">
       <h1 class="title" id="Home">Home</h1>
       Sample text
    </div>

    <div class="article">
       <h1 class="title" id="About">About</h1>
       Sample text
    </div>

    <div class="article">
       <h1 class="title" id="Clients">Clients</h1>
       Sample text
    </div>
```

So what you put after the # in the "href" attribute, refers to the "id" attribute in another html element. (without #)