# Redirect to #tag section from a different page

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, href, redirect

This question seems quite a duplicate. But it is not. Please spend a little time on this.

I have a word press menu that used in header. This is a single page website so I used the `section id` to redirect in the page like (`<a href="#sec-home">Home</a>`).Between this sections I need a smooth scroll effect so I use the following code.

```
$(".nav a[href^='#']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var position = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;

  $("body, html").animate({
    scrollTop: position
  } /* speed */ );
});
```

In this case I have two separate pages that are `Privacy & Policy` and `Terms & Conditions`. When I am in these pages I can't navigate to the `front-page sections` through the menu item click. Honestly it can not be, because I am using just `#sec-home`.

Now you can ask why don't you use `<a href="domain/#sec-home">Home</a>`. In here the problems I am facing are

1. I am getting the `/#sec-home` in my url
2. Smooth scroll effect is not available with this `href url`

What can be the solution that can solve my problem.

Comment: I asked a similar question two years ago and got a good answer that solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36137841/5641669

Comment: @Johannes Thank you for your reply sir. But at the same time I want to prevent the appearance on # tag in my url.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="../#sec-home">Home</a>` Only for home directory.

Comment: Header is common. I don't have separate headers for each and every page